# How can the OnTextChange action in filter list React-Admin change to OnSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, action, react-admin

In the React-Admin *filter* List component , each time the text changes, the GetList Action is called once, due to the high records, this overhead is very much and I want to change this call action with onSubmit.
Thank you

Comment: Can a bit more with a example, please? Which specific filter is affected? It would be awesome to have a CodeSandbox example to reproduce the issue. You can fork this one if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-admin

Comment: React-admin only provides a filter-as-you-type Filter component. If you need a filter-when-submit Filter component, you'll have to write it yourself, and use your component instead of React-admin's one. Also, the react-admin filter-as-you-type implementation uses *debounce*, so it shouldn't but a high overhead on your backend.